# Measure time for opening a large file using windows batch file

Tags: windows, file, batch-file

I would like to open few large files (word, excel, power-point etc) using a Windows batch file and I would like to record if the operation passed or failed. If it passed I would like to write to the log.  All that I have done is below, however, I am unable to measure the time it is taking for opening the files. I tried few scripts but they all failed.

please can you help me

```
echo StartTime = %Time% >> C:\Users\abc\Desktop\time.log
start winword.exe && (
echo Pass: MS Word opened at: %date% %time% >> C:\Users\abc\Desktop\time.log
) || (
echo Fail: MS Word Errored at: %date% %time% >> C:\Users\abc\Desktop\time.log
)
echo EndTime = %Time% >> C:\Users\abc\Desktop\time.log


echo StartTime = %Time% >> C:\Users\abc\Desktop\time.log
start excel.exe && (
echo Pass: MS Excel opened at: %date% %time% >> C:\Users\abc\Desktop\time.log
) || (
echo Fail: MS Excel Errored at: %date% %time% >> C:\Users\abc\Desktop\time.log
)
echo EndTime = %Time% >> C:\Users\abc\Desktop\time.log
```

Comment: `time /t` will return the time, but not the seconds.  `powershell get-date -format "G"` will return the date and time including the seconds.

Comment: Thanks Tony, however, i am looking for a simple batch file to measure time an application (large word file) takes to open, i have no issue with displaying time component. Also how to use this powershell get-date -format "G"...sorry i am new to coding & could not understand your answer very well

Answer (score 0):

here's bat file that returns the milliseconds passed since 1970 of when the file is last accessed (`lastaccessed.bat`) that takes a single argument - the file:

```
@if (@x)==(@y) @end /***** jscript comment ******
     @echo off
     cscript //E:JScript //nologo "%~f0"  %* 
     exit /b %errorlevel%

 @if (@x)==(@y) @end ******  end comment *********/

var FileSystemObj = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");

var ARGS = WScript.Arguments;
var filename=ARGS.Item(0);
var FileSystemObj = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
function getLastAccessed(obj){
    return obj.DateLastAccessed;
}

var file=FileSystemObj.GetFile(filename);
WScript.Echo((new Date(file.DateLastAccessed)).getTime());
```

Here's the [jeval.bat](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6212) by dbenham:

```
@if (@X)==(@Y) @end /* harmless hybrid line that begins a JScrpt comment

::************ Documentation ***********
:::
:::jEval  JScriptExpression  [/N]
:::jEval  /?
:::
:::  Evaluates a JScript expression and writes the result to stdout.
:::
:::  A newline (CR/LF) is not appended to the result unless the /N
:::  option is used.
:::
:::  The JScript expression should be enclosed in double quotes.
:::
:::  JScript string literals within the expression should be enclosed
:::  in single quotes.
:::
:::  Example:
:::
:::    call jEval "'5/4 = ' + 5/4"
:::
:::  Output:
:::
:::    5/4 = 1.25
:::

::************ Batch portion ***********
@echo off

if "%~1" equ "" (
  call :err "Insufficient arguments"
  exit /b
)
if "%~2" neq "" if /i "%~2" neq "/N" (
  call :err "Invalid option"
  exit /b
)
if "%~1" equ "/?" (
  setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
  for /f "delims=" %%A in ('findstr "^:::" "%~f0"') do (
    set "ln=%%A"
    echo(!ln:~3!
  )
  exit /b
)
cscript //E:JScript //nologo "%~f0" %*
exit /b

:err
>&2 echo ERROR: %~1. Use jeval /? to get help.
exit /b 1


************ JScript portion ***********/
if (WScript.Arguments.Named.Exists("n")) {
  WScript.StdOut.WriteLine(eval(WScript.Arguments.Unnamed(0)));
} else {
  WScript.StdOut.Write(eval(WScript.Arguments.Unnamed(0)));
}
```

Here's how you can calculate the passed time (in secconds) between two openings of a file:

```
@echo off
for /f %%a in ('lastaccessed.bat "c:\My Folder\book1.xlsx"') do set "time1=%%a"
excel.exe  "c:\My Folder\book1.xlsx"
for /f %%a in ('lastaccessed.bat "c:\My Folder\book1.xlsx"') do set "time2=%%a"

call jeval.bat "(%time2% - %time1%)/1000"
```

Is this what you looking for?

Comment: Many thanks for your answer, however i am getting following error                C:\Users\abc\Desktop\Scripts\lastaccessed.bat(17, 1) Microsoft JScript runtim
e error: File not found

C:\Users\abc\Desktop\Scripts\lastaccessed.bat(17, 1) Microsoft JScript runtim
e error: File not found

ERROR: Invalid option. Use jeval /? to get help.
time
Press any key to continue . . .

Comment: @raj - replace `"c:\My Folder\book1.xlsx"` with a valid path to excel file.

Comment: just to let you know if have copied your 1st code & saved it with file name lastaccessed.bat. then i copied 2nd script & saved it with file name jeval.bat. 3rd script i saved with execution.bat & i also changed the path of the spreadsheet to the one i have. i have also added echo & pause statements to check execution. Thanks

Comment: i have also added "start" before excel.exe in your last script otherwise it was failing, was i suppose to do that

Comment: it seems to be working now with after using start function before excel, however, time is always shown 0. my spreadsheet takes approximately 15 seconds to open, but code returns 0, please help

Comment: @raj - will check it.

Comment: @raj - check this - http://superuser.com/questions/251263/the-last-access-date-is-not-changed-even-after-reading-the-file-on-windows-7  - probably the key is not active on your machine

Comment: @npocmaka...sorry it seems i am not clear in my question, i am looking to script a windows batch file in which i want to open many documents i.e. word, excel, notepad etc of large size & would like to know how long it is taking for opening the files.